# Unexpected token <> (React Fragment) error from ESLint

Tags: reactjs, eslint, babeljs

I'm currently in the middle of upgrading dependencies from a project that's a couple of years old.  I'm having a hard time with eslint (and maybe babel?) complaining about react fragments? `<>`

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token

  378 | 
  379 |         return (
> 380 |             <>
      |              ^
```

I've upgraded babel-eslint to 10.1.0 and added that to my .eslint config file.  I was hoping that'd solve it but that's not helped.  I'm not sure if I'm looking in the wrong area or not?  As I say, the project is a couple of years old now and upgrading packages is new to me.

For example - I think `babel-core` is now `@babel/core`.  I'm not sure outside of installing the newer package what else I need to do?  And this may be my issue?  But I'm not too sure

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below and see if it resolves your issue:

install babel-eslint

```
npm install babel-eslint --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add -D babel-eslint
```

Secondly, add this configuration in your .eslintrc file

```
{
   "parser":"babel-eslint"
}
```

Comment: I currently have that in my eslint config file, it's just not working for some reason!